# Is there a way to training a CNN model without changing the outputs of Convolution Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am training a model to detect opening and closing of a door. When I visualize the convolution layers the model shows that it is detecting the opening and closing but after the training it stops detecting it. As if the convolution kernal itself has changed. 
Does anyone know the reason and please suggest a way to stop changing the kernal while training the model?

Comment: This is a very generic question. You need to ask a specific question about a problem you are having.

Comment: We'll need to see some code.